# Run http tests until AMQ msgs consumed

Tags: scala, gatling

We're running Gatling/Scala to load test an application in the following manner:

1. Post a ton of messages to AMQ.
2. Run a number of REST calls while messages are being consumed.

The Gatling setup looks like this:

```scala
setUp(
    JmsScenario.run inject(atOnceUsers(events)) protocols(JmsScenario.jmsConnect),
    HttpScenario.run inject(constantUsersPerSec(httpThroughput) during(httpDuration)) protocols(HttpScenario.protocol),
)
```

But instead of using `during(...)` I'd like to use something like `untilAmqMessageQueueIsEmpty()`. Is there some (fairly easy) way to accomplish this?

Comment: That's too application specific, that's something you'll have to implement yourself.

Comment: @StéphaneLANDELLE I'm new to Scale/Gatling, would you say this is a 5-line or a 100-line implementation? If the former: any pointers to something similar or how to commence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `asLongAs` and call some custom code (in Java if you don't know Scala).
See https://gatling.io/docs/current/general/scenario/#aslongas.

```scala
// isAmqMessageQueueIsEmpty is something only you can code
// It has to return a Boolean
asLongAs(session => isAmqMessageQueueIsEmpty()) {
   ???
}
```